# How to change user selected text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like to change the text that will be pasted without changing the selection's appearance on the screen, similar to what the Linux [xsel](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xsel) command can do.

Ideally this would work on all platforms and browsers, but at the very least I want it to work on Chrome running on Linux.

My usecase is that I have a button that selects a block of shell commands from the web page (this is done by some library magic that I have no easy access to) and I want to add a terminating newline "behind the scenes" so that when the user middle-clicks in the console, he gets the text that appears highlighted on the screen plus a newline.

How to do it?

Comment: And what is your question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The question is how to do it.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text) for how to get the selected text in a page. Then you just add a newline (\n or <br/> depending on how you want to use it).

Comment: How do I "just add a newline"?  What I want to happen is that when the user pastes, the newline will be added to the pasted text.